# mfc dialog opens only after mouse move when using QT

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

I have an interesting issue. My MFC dialog `CManageDlg` is calling another MFC dialog `CmyMfcDlg` using this call, on press of a button

```
    void CManageDlg::OnBnClickedBt()
    {
        CmyMfcDlg ipmfc;
        if ( ipmfc.DoModal() != IDOK )
        {
            return MyError;
        }
    }
```

Here is :

```
BOOL CmyMfcDlg ::OnInitDialog() 
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    CString tmpStr;
    UpdateData(FALSE);

   CDC  dc;
   dc.Attach(::GetDC(this->m_hWnd));

   int  mx = dc.GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES);
   int  my = dc.GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES);
   // lots of initializations 
}
```

The problem is once `OnBnClickedBt()` is triggered by press of a button (`ON_BN_CLICKED`), `CmyMfcDlg` wait and does not open until mouse is moved! I do not know how these two are connected. I meant mouse move and opening the dialog.

EDIT1:
it turns out that this issue only happened when using **QT** User Interface, if I called the same function using UI written in MFC, it works fine with no problem!

Edit2:
I noticed also that this issue happened only when you open the dialog on the stack (modal) `ipmfc.DoModal()`, on the heap (modelless) everything is fine!

Comment: Is your second dialog in DLL?

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin both dialogs are in DLL. Both are being called from .exe

Comment: So I believe its regular DLL. Why don't you use MFC extension library for that?

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin thanks for the advise. Yes, it is regular DLL. Not sure about the MFC extension library, I will check it.

Comment: Yes, you should use MFC Extension library for MFC stuff. This way you wont need `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());` and there will be no problems with your message pump.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin what MFC extension library do you recommend? in my research it seems that there are several of them!

Comment: You misunderstood. You should use **MFC Extension** type of DLL for your own DLL instead of regular one. Check **New Project Wizard** of VS. It does use message pump of your CWinApp.

Comment: I believe the problem is that QT has its own message pump that "eats" some messages.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin, I noticed also that this issue happened only when you open the dialog on the stack, on the heap everything is fine!